# Testing Generated Connection String by EntityConnectionStringBuilder

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

I want to test the connection string generated by EntityConnectionStringBuilder.
I've used the following code to do this.

```
using (EntityConnection connection = new EntityConnection(ConnectionStringGenerator(username, password, server)))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        MessageBox.Show("Connected");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
```

This code works, but it takes a few seconds for an error to occur when an exception occurs. What is the problem?
Is there a better solution?
Please guide me.

Comment: What's the exception you are getting? Are you connecting to the database server which is located somewhere else such as Azure?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test here? That the underlying provider throws an exception if passed an invalid connection string? If so.. why?

Comment: @stuartd I tried to test my connection string

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I don't get exception, I said when exception raised it take a few seconds

Comment: If you provide a wrong server address in the connection string, then the ADO.NET will try to connect to the server for  the time specified in ConnectionTimeout value before throwing the exception. That's why it takes time to throw the exception. You can reduce the value of ConnectionTimeout if you don't want to wait too long to connect to the server. This also may backfire if the server is live but responds too slow due to network or any other factor.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Is it possible to change the Connection Timeout in Entity Framework?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout?view=netframework-4.8